# how to run big python script in php using browser

Tags: php, python, browser

I have tried all the php method to run my python script in php like exec(),shell_exec(),system(),popen() etc but nothing is working , if try the php from terminal it is working fine

Here is my script

```
test.php

<?php
  $term = system(python /home/user/script.py /input-path/input/ /output-path/output
 )>
```

Comment: if you use Apache or Nginx then you can check Apache/Nginx log for errors.

Comment: Error log says *31 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream @furas

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $term = system("/usr/bin/python /home/user/script.py /input-path/input/ /output-path/output"
 )>
```

Comment: I tried this also same issue and th nginx error log says Error log says *31 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream @massiou